# Python: Convert HTML to AsciiDoc

Tags: python, html, asciidoc

I am looking for a Python tool to convert html into [AsciiDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AsciiDoc) markup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such a tool exists, because of the flexible structure of HTML files.

But you can easily write one. If you know the specific format of an HTML document, just [parse html](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and construct the desired AsciiDoc.

Answer (score 7):

Not a tool based in Python, but in Haskell: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/ - this awesome tool can transform as many formats as you can imagine. Highly recommended.

Comment: I am working with asciidoctor in ruby and pandoc was the way to go from html to asciidoc thanks to your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

We are developing to-asciidoc project. https://github.com/asciidocfx/to-asciidoc